# Codeigniter autoload session is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

the problem is this, when i login into the project, it creates the session, but when i try to acces the session from other controller, or even from the same controller, the session data doesn't existe, i have loaded session from autoload, and i also tried loading the session in the constructor, but the issue is still there. 
forgive for my english, this is not my native language, i hope you can help me please, thanks

Controller login function:

```
public function do_login(){
        $user = $this->input->post('usuario');
        $passwd = $this->input->post('clave');
        $data = $this->login_model->do_login($user,$passwd);

        if($data){
            $this->session->set_userdata("login",(array)$data); 
            //print_r($this->session->userdata());
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 1,'message'=>'Bienvenido','idPerfil'=> $data->idPerfil));
        }else
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 0,'message'=>'Usuario o contraseña incorrecto'));
    }

constructor
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $this->load->library('Mobile_Detect');
        //$this->load->model('cat_usuarios_model');
    //  $this->load->model('cat_sucursales_model');
    $this->load->library("session");

    }
```

this is the autoload.php line

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database','form_validation','email');
```

Comment: Have you set the config sessions correct.

Comment: well, this is the session config
$config['encryption_key'] = '49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

but as i said, it was working in the server, usually the only configuration that i do is the encription key and it's enough with that

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with configuration.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL
```

This is causing the failure.

If `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';` then `$config['sess_save_path']` **must be set to an absolute path** to the folder where the files will be saved.

You can create a folder for the files. See the [documentation for more information](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver).  Or, you can use the following.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

It is probably better to create a specific folder to save session files than to use `sys_get_temp_dir()`. It is a tiny bit more work because setting permissions and ownership of the folder can be tricky if you just learning how to do those things.

Comment: I use `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH .'cache/sessions/';`

Comment: @wolfgang1983, I use a folder at the same level as site public folder - htdocs. `config['sess_save_path'] =  substr(FCPATH, 0, strpos(FCPATH, 'htdocs/'))."sessions/");`